# Answered questions appear as unanswered on feed

Tags: bug, android-app, unanswered-questions, android-app-feed

I've noticed this a few times on the Feed activity on the Android app, but never thought anything of it.

Why does this question (*How To auto enable checkbox?*) appear as "Unanswered" when there is an icon which denotes there are 5 answers, one of which has been marked as the answer?

Dragging down to refresh doesn't seem to clear the unanswered flag either.

**Device:** Nexus 5

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian w h y  i s  t h e  i c o n  g r e e n  t h e n? Sorry, couldn't resist :) But seriously, if it is indeed caching then the data is already present and correct because the icon shows it - the title just needs to be updated to reflect the same as the icon surely?

Comment: I'm getting this too.